# Clipping polygons to the base map shoreline

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

I was given shapefile polygons that were created with ArcGIS and I when I imported them to QGIS 3.1 they are no longer clipped to the shorelines of a base map. I am hoping there is an easy way to match the polygons to the shoreline. I have attached a picture for a visual aid.

[image]

Comment: They seem to represent a digitisation of a specific basemap. It is unlikely that they will fit another map at a high scale. Can you load the same map in the background as was used for digitisation?

Comment: I will ask around and see if I can find that exact map. thanks for the answer